# Sandbox refresh behavior of copied id's

Tags: sandbox-refresh

I read the Salesforce documents around the data that gets copied when a sandbox is refreshed, but still wanted to make sure my understanding is correct on the list of items that are copied over when a sandbox is refreshed or created.

Can you please help understand the behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as Prod.

All ID values are copied verbatim, including user ID values, field ID values, object ID values, record ID values, record type ID values, and so on. The *only* exception to this rule is the Organization ID is changed to allow Salesforce to uniquely identify the org you're logging in to.

A sandbox is literally a copy of production (except obviously record data for partial/developer/developer pro sandboxes).

Comment: However, conversely, when you deploy a new component to a target environment that does not include that component, the ID will not match.